# Allure reports using protractor and jasmine - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, jasmine, protractor, jenkins-plugins

I have problem with generate allure report in jenkins.

I will try to describe my projesc briefly.
I use protractor and jasmine, here is my project in WebStorm (structure):

[image]

My config.js

exports.config = {

```
framework: 'jasmine2',

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'
},

suites: {
    smoke: ['tests/smoke/LoginTest.js'],
},

baseUrl : 'www.myurl.com',

    onPrepare: function () {
        var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter());
        jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function(done){
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                    return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                }, 'image/png')();
                done();
            })
        });
    }};
```

I've installed Allure plugin in Jenkins, created multi-conf project, and configured it like that:

[image]

After Run build in Jenkins build fails (put browser window is opening and test pass). Output from my console:

[image]

But something is generating in workspace:

[image]

But my Allure Report is empty:

[image]

I've noticed that when I comment in config.js:

```
 onPrepare: function () {
            var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter());
            jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function(done){
                browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                    allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                        return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                    }, 'image/png')();
                    done();
                })
            });
        }
```

Then build success.

[image]

So the problem is that I don't know what I missed or what I do wrong it's not gerating/opening this report. Maybe someone smarter than me will tell mi where I'm doing mistake becouse I have no idea

Comment: please update your `path` as `${WORKSPACE}/allure-report`

Comment: Which "path" do you mean? In jenkins, after build -> allure report?

Comment: After selecting `post build action` as `Allure Report`, you can see that field or refer your attached screen shot.!!

Comment: so I tryed to do that, but build was still failed. I only noticed that there was created new folder, with html, css and so on, but after click on Allure report, it was still empty. Maybe there is problem with pom.xml? I don't have this file...